# How to “cut” sda5 to sda2? or how to boot GParted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm using CentOS 6.4 via VMWare. At once, I created my PC just 20Gb

But now, I need to expand my PC to 120Gb. So i've add 100Gb by using VMware. But it doesn't work when i check it via samba.

I try to use df -h and i see this :

[root@test-cba /]# df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda2              18G  2.5G   15G  15% /

tmpfs                 495M   72K  495M   1% /dev/shm

/dev/sda1             291M   33M  243M  12% /boot

/dev/sda5              79G  184M   75G   1% /mnt/smb

Via Samba, my PC is still 20Gb. So i think /dev/sda5 has not added to sda2 to expand HDD memory.

I'm new with it and someone on google told me try to use GParted. I've downloaded live ISO and defined it to VMWare at field CD/DVD(IDE). But when i boot my PC (F12), it just boot to CentOS ISO.

My question is: How to expand sda2 to 120Gb? or How to boot GParted ISO? or Anyway else to make this possible?

Answer (score 3):

By enlarging your disk, you have told your Host that the space reserved to your guest is now larger, but you have not told your guest of this, yet. GParted serves exactly this purpose. When you will have started GParted, you will see your disk as a large (120 GB) unit, only partially occupied (20 GB), with 100GB free. You will then instruct GParted to expand the existing partition in the free space next to it. Since GParted comes with a nice GUI, a little trial and error will show you how.

The more difficult part is obtaining GParted. For CentOS, you will find instructions [on this very site](https://serverfault.com/questions/156156/how-to-install-gparted-on-centos). Mka e sure you read the top **two** answers.